# Filtering in Cypher inside Multiple Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Take the following pattern which starts with a node labelled “Conversation” and has one long chain of [:RESPONSE] relationships.

There are many nodes in this pattern, but we only care about 2 of them: (Answer) and (Element).
And there is only one relationship we care about: [:RESPONSE]

```
(Conversation) <-[:RESPONSE]-(unimportant_node)<-[:RESPONSE]
..()..()..()..(Answer)<-()..()..(Element)..().().()..()..()..
(Answer)…()..(Element)<—()..()..(Answer)-..()-..(Element)<-..().()
```

**What I want is to find ALL the (Answers), each with its associated (Element).**

**The variable part**: the number of nodes between (Conversation) and (Answer), and also between (Answer) and (Element) is variable.

**The invariable part**: After each (Answer) there is an (Element) node, which is basically associated to that (Answer). Then, at some point, there is another (Answer), which also has an associated (Element).

---

**What I'm doing**:
Because I want to retrieve all the (Answers), I use (c:Conversation)<-[:RESPONSE*]–(a:Answer).

Then, because I don’t know how many nodes are between (Answer) and its associated (Element), I use again [:RESPONSE*].

So, my query looks like this:

```
match (c:Conversation) <- [:RESPONSE*] - (a:Answer) <-[:RESPONSE*]-(e:Element)
```

this brings ALL the (Elements) following each (Answer), which is not good, because I’m only interested in the FIRST (Element) following each (Answer).

I did manage to find this ***solution***:

```
match (c:Conversation) <- [:RESPONSE*] - (a:Answer) <- [:RESPONSE*] - (e:Element)
with c,a,head(collect(e)) as first_e  //could also use: collect(e)[0] as first_e
    ...code continues...
```

However, I’m looking for an alternative solution which would simply just find the first (Element) after each (Answer) and then stop, thus making Cypher work a lot less.

---

Playing with this, I’ve noticed that it’s quite easy to bring only the first (Answer) if I want to. *(In my case, however, I want all of them, so I’m not doing it).*

```
match (c:Conversation) <- [:RESPONSE*] - (a:Answer) <- [:RESPONSE*]-(e:Element)
where not(  (:Answer)<- [:RESPONSE]-(a)  )
```

I figured there must be an easy way to apply this technique to bring just the first (Element) after each (Answer), so I’ve tried:

```
match (c:Conversation) <- [:RESPONSE*]-(a:Answer)
with c,a
match (a) <-[:RESPONSE*]-(e:Element)
           where not( (:Answer)<- [:RESPONSE]-(a) )
```

Unfortunately, this logic is not applied in a for_each (Answer) scope, but rather it’s applied for the whole query. As such, this will only bring 1 row of results:

```
conversation | the_very_last_Answer | the_very_last_element
```

I’ve also tried putting the MATCH in a FOREACH, but I get a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and do it using `apoc.cypher.run` procedure. Something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Conversation)<-[:RESPONSE*]-(a:Answer)
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
    WITH {a} AS a
    MATCH (a)-[:RESPONSE*]->(e:Element)
    RETURN e LIMIT 1',
    {a:a}) YIELD value
RETURN c, value.e
```

With `apoc.cypher.run` you can execute a subquery with `LIMIT` (1, in this case) per row.

Comment: Related, Bruno's answer is one approach mentioned by the Neo4j knowledge base article on [limiting results per row](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/), and should work great. Other approaches are mentioned in the article, and may be useful in other cases.

Comment: Thank you Bruno and InverseFalcon. I need to look into APOC, as I was unaware of it! Thank you for the suggestion.